# jQuery: Resize event does not fire when using multiple events in a selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to assign multiple events to a selector instead of creating separate event.

```
$('element').on('click resize scroll mouseover', function(){
 // do something
});
```

The problem is that the resize event does not fire while the others do.

Comment: As per doc first argument :  ___One or more space-separated event types and optional namespaces___ , it's provided in documentation clearly....

Comment: How much easier could you want it? All you have to do is specify the events you want to target separated by spaces. Whats wrong with that? Failing that you could create a string array and pass that in as the argument for the selector

Comment: Since the OP has given the 'answer' in his code, perhaps that is an indication that this is not the question he is actually answering.

'Assigning multiple events' to a selector could also mean he wants to trigger multiple events, rather than listen for them.

Better to ask for clarification than make silly comments.

Rahul can you clarify. Do you mean you want to TRIGGER multiple events on the same item?

Comment: @Toby The issue seems to be pertaining to the resize event which doesn't seems to be working although other events are working.

Comment: @Kendo, Yes I think the comment talking about telepathic links is a pretty silly response. If the OP has posted the code he did, it should be obvious that it's not working for him, and there must be some other issue to help with. Surely StackOverflow is for helping other programmers, not just making comments which don't help. As you can see, by asking the OP more about the question, we can maybe help him.

Comment: Rahul - the resize event is normally triggered on the window, not an element. So you probably want to remove that from your list, because you are mixing events which belong to the element, and events which belong to the window.

$('element').on('click scroll mouseover', function(){});
$(window).on('resize', function(){});

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation for `on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) states that the event argument is one or more space-separated event types and optional namespaces, such as `click` or `keydown.myPlugin`. So essentially, what you'r showing in your question is the answer itself.

In the next snippet you can see that clicking an moving the mouse over the element both trigger the listener. What you do inside there is entirely up to you

```
$(function() {
    $("#target").on("click mouseover", function(ev) {
    $("#output").text($("#output").text() + "\n"+"event triggered");
  })
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("#target").on("click mouseover", function(ev) {
    $("#output").text($("#output").text() + "\n"+"event triggered");
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target">I'm a target</div>
<pre id="output">

</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

space seperated is correct.

```
$('element').on('click resize scroll mouseover', function(){
 // do something
});
```

But if the element is live one, you should use this statement.

```
$(document).on('click resize scroll mouseover', 'element', function(){
 // do something
});
```

Comment: Are you sure comma-separated? I think event names should be space-separated.

Comment: @Mike Why you are not trying that?

Comment: the selector can be comma separated not the events, answer of the question is ___yes___ :D

Comment: if the element is live one, you should use this statement
$(document).on("click resize","element",function() {

}

Comment: @UnknownUser you see why I wasn't trying that? I have been using it with space-separated events, I was just reminding the answerer that the list is comma-separated ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('element').on('click mouseover', function(e) {
 // your code here
});
```

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the .bind() method is used for attaching an event handler directly to elements.. http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: While you are correct and the bind() method is not deprecated, on() is preferred.

Comment: @kendo yes on() is preferred to bind.

$(selector).on(event,childSelector,data,function,map);
Multiple event values are separated by space. Must be a valid event